# Cast to objectid failed for value object object at path mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to NodeJS and MongoDB and ran through following problem while creating a sample app

```
// ************  this is  testusers.js file  ************//

var userdetails = require('userdetails');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;

var geekDetails = new schema({
    description: String,
    details: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'userDetails'
    }
});
module.exports = {
    model: mongoose.model('geekDetails',geekDetails),
    schema: geekDetails
};


// ************  this is  user.js file  ************//

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userDetails = new schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
});

module.exports = {
    model: mongoose.model('userDetails',userDetails),
    schema: userDetails
};


// ************  this is  create.js file [used to save the details to DB]  *******//

var testusers = require('testusers.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

adduser = function(firstName,lastName,email,password,passwordConfirmation,description,callback){

    new testusers.model({
        description: description,
        details: {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            email: email,
            password: password
        }
    }).save(function(err,result){
        if (err){
            callback(err,null);
        }
        else {
            callback(null,result);
        }
    });
```

When I tried to save the details it returned the following error "**cast to objectid failed for value object object at path 'details'** " I am sure I am doing something wrong with schemas but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving reference document like this won't work with mongoose this way. Here is one alternative. Essentially, you need to save the embedded document (`userdetails`) first and use the id to save the parent (`testuser`).

```
adduser= function(firstName,lastName,email,password,passwordConfirmation,
    description,callback){

    new userDetails.model({
        firstName:firstName,
        lastName:lastName,
        email:email,
        password:password
    }).save(function(err,doc){
        new testusers.model({
            description:description,
            details: doc._id
        }).save(function(err,result){
            if(err){callback(err,null);}
            else{callback(null,result);}
        });
    });
}
```

Using promises may make this code better to read but this should give the idea.